# How to get started right with a ASP.NET MVC 4 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Last time I worked on a sizable project with MVC was version 2 and it was a while ago, so I've been out of the loop.  Now I am getting started on a small reporting project.

Basically, there will be a half-dozen pre-canned reports and some with criteria to be selected by the user.  The users will access the content from computers and iOS/Android devices.

What are some of the libraries that I should include in the project to get me going fast and provide a quality product?

So far I got ELMAH and MiniProfiler.

Comment: There aren't many changes in MVC4 that would change your workflow - I'm using MVC2 in my own work because I don't feel compelled to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My list:

- Webapi - Create and use an API for your communication with Android/iOS
- NHibernate - ORM - if you think your project requires one
- Structuremap - Dependency Injection
- Automapper - map domain objects to viewmodels
- Squishit - I personally love this library for minification but you can also check out the inbuilt mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

I think mvc dose not have change workflow from first version but I have checklist for project

1. Use [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) for Typed Address
2. for Test I use [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)
3. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for mapping viewModel
4. [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for error handeling
5. Entityframework
6. [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)
7. Bootstrap or jqueryUi
8. [StructureMapper](http://structuremap.net/) for DI container